# onkeyup function inside for loop of php script

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use onkeyup function inside for loop of a php script. 
The value in the second box in each row should be 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 respectively irrespective of the entry in the first box.  But I am not getting the desired result. The final result (ie 25) is showing for each box.

```
<?php
 for ($i=1;$i<=5;++$i)
  {
    ${"k3".$i}=5*$i;
?>
<html>
 <script>
   function gftt2(xx1){
   var drr2=<?php echo ${"k3".$i}?>;
   document.getElementById(xx1).value=drr2;
  }
</script>

<input type="text" size="1" maxlength="" id="<?php echo "dd1{$i}"?>"   name="dd1[$i]"  onkeyup="gftt2('<?php echo  "dd4{$i}"?>')"/>
<input type="text" size="1" maxlength="" id="<?php echo "dd4{$i}"?>"  name="dd4[$i]" /><br/>

</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Please help.

Comment: change the function name for each loop.

Comment: You should have the HTML-tag and the function outside the loop. In the loop you just add an `onkeyup="theFunction(<?= $theValue ?>)"`. No need to make mutliple functions if it's only one value that changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function gftt2(id, value) 
    {
       document.getElementById(id).value = value;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    for ($i=1;$i<=5;++$i) {
        $value = 5*$i;

    ?>

        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="" id="dd1<?php echo $i ?>" name="dd1[<?php echo $i ?>]" onkeyup="gftt2('dd4<?php echo $i ?>', '<?php echo $value?>')"/>
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="" id="dd4<?php echo $i ?>" name="dd4[<?php echo $i ?>]" /><br/>

    <?php 
    } 
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

It's untested. :o